# Ready, Set, Deathmatch

Tags: word, visual, rebus

1. [image: item]
2. [image: item]
3. [image: item]
4. [image: item]
5. [image: item]

> But can you survive the '*_* _ _ _ _ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess:

1.

> Q (Queue)

2.

> U (You)

3.

> A (AAAAAAA!!!!)

4.

> K (Okay)

5.

> E (Eel)

But can you survive the

> 'quake (earthquake)

Comment: Lovely :) And of course- the title references a game by the same name!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess:

1.

> **Queue**

2.

> **You**

3.

> "**Eeeee!**"

4.

> (Hell! I said:) **Ell**

5.

> (*When the moon hits your eye like big pizza pie:*) that's a Moray **Eel**

Which combine to

> **Quell** when you read out each word and pick a letter that sounds like it. (The surviving bit is not so clear to me. Google suggests Hunger Games, which seems to fit the topic too.)

Comment: I'm glad I added the title :') You've got a good guess here! Correct: 1, 2, 5. You've also got the correct thinking of rot13(hfvat n fcrpvsvp yrggre). For our poor homework-swamped friend, I'll say... what is the expected answer a mother wants to hear? (With some teenager attitude thrown in, of course!)

Comment: Noticed: Correct answer for 5, but there is one letter more prevalent in the animal's name :) That's the one you'll want!

Comment: I thought 5 was rot13(Rkbtbegu sebz fgne jnef) haha :)